# Não consigo declarar variáveis como string no meu código em C++

Tags: c++, string, biblioteca

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

void print(float arr[], string nome[], int x){

    for (int i=0; i < x; i++){
        printf("O aluno %s obteve media de %2.2f\n", nome[i],arr[i]);
    }

}

void ordem(float arr[], string nome[], int x){

    float aux;
    string caux;

    for (int i=0; i < x; i++){
        for (int j=i+1; j < x; j++){
            if (arr[j] > arr[i]){
                    aux = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = aux;

                    caux = nome[i];
                    nome[i] = nome[j];
                    nome[j] = caux;
            }
        }
    }

    print(arr, nome, x);

}


int main(){
    float A1[19], A2[19];
    float media[19];
    int i=0;
    const int x=5;
    string nome[x];

    while (i < x){
        printf("\nDigite o nome do Aluno: ");
        scanf("%s", &nome[i]);

        printf("\nDigite a nota A1 do %d aluno: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &A1[i]);
        printf("\nDigite a nota A2 do %d aluno: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &A2[i]);
        media[i] = (A1[i] + A2[i])/2;
        i++;
    }

    ordem(media, nome, x);

    return 0;
}
```

Usei as IDEs CodeBlocks e Dev-C++ e continuou a dar erro.[image: LOGs]

Comment: Evite misturar C e C++. Especifique std:: antes de string.

Comment: Já que está usando C++, use std::vector ao invés de arrays do C. Lembre-se de usar std::, que é o namespace onde as funções do standard estão. Se não quiser, declare: using namespace std;. Mas recomendo ler isto na SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar o `string` em C++, você deverá especificá-lo do namespace de onde o mesmo está vindo.
No caso do `string`, o namespace é o `std`. No seu caso, basta inserir antes de cada uso de string o texto `std::`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

void print(float arr[], std::string nome[], int x){

    for (int i=0; i < x; i++){
        printf("O aluno %s obteve media de %2.2f\n", nome[i],arr[i]);
    }

}

void ordem(float arr[], std::string nome[], int x){

    float aux;
    std::string caux;

    for (int i=0; i < x; i++){
        for (int j=i+1; j < x; j++){
            if (arr[j] > arr[i]){
                    aux = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = aux;

                    caux = nome[i];
                    nome[i] = nome[j];
                    nome[j] = caux;
            }
        }
    }

    print(arr, nome, x);

}


int main(){
    float A1[19], A2[19];
    float media[19];
    int i=0;
    const int x=5;
    std::string nome[x];

    while (i < x){
        printf("\nDigite o nome do Aluno: ");
        scanf("%s", &nome[i]);

        printf("\nDigite a nota A1 do %d aluno: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &A1[i]);
        printf("\nDigite a nota A2 do %d aluno: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &A2[i]);
        media[i] = (A1[i] + A2[i])/2;
        i++;
    }

    ordem(media, nome, x);

    return 0;
}
```

Você também pode declarar o using para o namespace para evitar digitar o std::. No caso, ficaria:

```
using namespace std;
```

Com o código acima, declarado, preferencialmente, em um .cpp, você evita a necessidade de digitar o std:: antes do uso de string ou qualquer outro membro do namespace.

Recomendo que leia este post também: [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Assim como o anonimo comentou, evite misturar C e c++. Use apenas se alguma biblioteca de terceiro que você vá utilizar necessite ou caso trabalhe num código legado.

No seu caso, recomendo ler sobre std::vector que pode lhe ser útil.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa especificar o namespace que engloba a classe `string`, nesse caso o namespace é `std`. Para definir um objeto do tipo string precisa utilizar o tipo `std::string`.

Caso precise utilizar essa classe muitas vezes no código você pode evitar ter que especificar o namespace todas as vezes usando o comando `using` para referenciar o namespace ou uma função específica do namespace dentro de um escopo do código, exemplo:

Especifica o namespace `std` globalmente:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std; // referencia todo o namespace std da biblioteca string

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string s = "exemplo";
    // code ...
}
```

Para especificar uma função ou classe específica (é útil quando você vai utilizar somente uma ou poucas funções da biblioteca):

```
#include <string>
using std::string; // usa a classe std::string

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string s = "exemplo";
    // code ...
}
```